# jQuery $(this) selector function and limitations

Tags: jquery, selector, this

I need help understanding `$(this)`. Is it possible to narrow the focus of "this" within the parentheses or does "this" preclude the use of any other attributes?

For example: I don't understand why this code:

```
$(this).children("div")
```

can't be rewritten like this:

```
$(this + " div")
```

without having to resort to something like:

```
$('#'+$(this).attr("id")+ " div")
```

Also, can you point me to 'this' in the jQuery documentation? It is difficult to use 'this' as a search term for obvious reasons.

Comment: Given the duck-typing nature of this language, how is it supposed to know how you want `this` to be used? Your example implies it should be a string to which you can append things to.

Comment: I debated including a complete example using a generic function, but decided to keep it generic in hopes that someone like Nick would come along ;)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/this) isn't a jQuery "thing", but a [basic JavaScript one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/this).  It can't be re-written the way you have in examples because it's an object, in particular either a DOM element or a jQuery object (depending on what context you're in).  So if you did this:

```
 $(this + " div")
```

What you'd *really* be doing is calling [`.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) on [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/this) to concatenate the strings, resulting in:

```
 $("[object Object] div")
```

....which isn't a valid selector.

As for further reading, I believe [this article](http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/) continues to be one of the best references/resources to learn what `this` (a context keyword) means.

---

Per comment requests, some examples of what `this` is in various places:

- Event handlers, for example: `$("selector").click(function() { alert(this); });`

  - `this` refers to the DOM element the event handler is being triggered on.
- Inside a jQuery plugin, for example: `$.fn.myPlugin = function() { alert(this); });`

  - `this` is the jQuery object the plugin was called/chained on, for example: `$("selector").myPlugin();`, `this` is that `$("selector")` jQuery object.
- Inside any generic function, for example: `function myFunc() { alert(this); };`

  - `this` is the context you're in, whether it be an object or something else, a few examples:
  - `$("selector").click(myFunc);` - `this` is the DOM element, like above
  - `$("selector").click(function() { myFunc(); });` - `this` is the global content, `window`
  - `myFunc.call(whatThisIs, arg1, arg2);` - `this` is `whatThisIs`

    - See [`Function.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [`Function.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) for more info

Comment: +1 for good explanation of the reason you can't do it that way

Comment: could you elaborate for the question asker on what `this` is and what it generally refers to in most contexts in relation to jQuery usage (i.e. I'm thinking inside of plugins, event handlers, etc)?

Comment: Though you could probably monkey patch the object's `.toString` to return the correct id...

Comment: +1 - Been looking for an answer like this for a while now! I see a lot of people answering questions using `$(this + 'string')` - though not correct, it does appear to work. Any idea why?

Answer (score 11):

Use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find)

```
$( this ).find( 'div' )
```

Or use the `context` parameter to [`jQuery( selector, context )`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery) (internally, it just calls find anyway...)

```
$( 'div', this )
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` is not a string representing a css selector(such as `div`,`#my_id` or `.my_class`).
When passing `this` as a argument for the jQuery function, it returns a jQuery object based on the current element(what this referes to),  so you cannot use something like `$(this + selector)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this:  http://api.jquery.com/each/

Basically `this` is the DOM element that the callback is referencing.  You can't do `$(this + " div")` because you are adding a string to an element.  You first need to get the id like in your third code snippet.

By the way, `$(this).children("div")` is not the same as `$('#'+$(this).attr("id")+" div")`

First off, `this` might not have an ID, in which case the second way won't work at all.  And even if it does have an ID, that second code is actualy `$(this).find("div")`.  If you want children only you have to do:

```
$('#'+$(this).attr("id") + " > div")
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you must to understand what is **this**, it is depend on an context.
When you call $ function it will return a jQuery object.

```
$(this).children("div")
```

It means from specific object, get all children, see the below link:
http://jsfiddle.net/vietean/f2Yrg/