# Populate input text with drop down select option text

Tags: jquery, select

I have a classified ads site and I want in the post ads form when a user select some options from drop down list the text from that option to populate automatically an input field.
I managed to get the values for that select using .val, but when i use .text the input field is filled with all options available in the select. I have a demo to understand better [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/A8Nxp/240/)

Comment: a) You didn't really tell your problem.
b) You could just search for this stuff easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want the selected item `text` you have to use the `:selected` selector like this:

```
var selected_item = $(":selected", this).text()
```

See: [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/erwin21/A8Nxp/246/)

More info about the [:selected Selector](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)

Comment: This isn't the correct way to select the element, you should use `this` as the [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) for getting the `:selected` element, $(':selected', this) - [read here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611233/jquery-this-selector-function-and-limitations)

Answer (score 1):

To get the selected value of a dropdown use the val() instead of text(). Change:

```
var selected_item = $(this).text()
```

to

```
 var selected_item = $(this).val()
```