# Get the value of msDropdown Jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the json version of the msDropdown plugin found here: [LINK](https://github.com/marghoobsuleman/ms-Dropdown/blob/master/examples/byjson.html) and I just need to know something that is probably relatively simple..  how do I get the value of say the example page they show on that link?

I am weak at JS but this was my attempt:

```
var selectedIndex = $("#byjson").val();
$("#byjson").change(function() {
    alert("value =" + selectedIndex);
})
```

Right now I just need it to show in the alert box and then I am sure I can continue working with it to get it where I want it but I am not able to get anything to show in the alert box.

Again this is probably like ABC's simple but I think I am missing something key here :D

Comment: try `alert(this.value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the selectedIndex after the change, so move that inside change function

```
$("#byjson").change(function() {
    var selectedIndex = $("#byjson").val();
    alert("value =" + selectedIndex); })
```

you can also use this inside change function

```
$("#byjson").change(function() {
        var selectedIndex = $(this).val();
        alert("value =" + selectedIndex); })
```

Comment: You rock, thanks -- I knew it must have been a simple fix ;)

Can you tell me what $(this) does, Im guessing is looks for the element that is associated with what you are calling like in this case #byjson.  Is that correct?

Comment: this is the current html element that the change event is triggered. $(this) will give the JQuery object of that element. See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611233/jquery-this-selector-function-and-limitations?answertab=active#tab-top) for better understanding of this in JQuery functions