# Javascript passing this to functions

Tags: javascript, variables, this

I'm not used to working with `this` and trying to make some simple functions pass it back and forth. I'm not quite sure what javascript is expecting, but I don't think I'm doing it right.

```
$(".search-result").each(function() {
    var x  = $(this).find('.past-positions ol').children()
    console.log(x)
    //this prints as expected
    pastJobs(this)
    // this does not
})

function pastJobs() {
    var x  = $(this).find('.past-positions ol').children()
    console.log(x)
    // this prints as undefined
}
```

I assume its possible to pass `this` to functions, but I don't think I'm doing it in the right way.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611233/jquery-this-selector-function-and-limitations

Comment: `this` and `$(this)` are two very different things, as the latter is a specific jQuery object while the first change on the how the object is called

Answer (score 6):

Try `pastJobs.call(this)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, here `pastJobs(this)` you're passing the lexical context `this` as param rather than binding that context to the function.

You can use the function `bind` to achieve what you want:

```
pastJobs.bind(this)()
```

Comment: Is there a reason to use `bind()` followed by `()` instead of `call()`?

Comment: @MarkMeyer no, as you may know, the function `bind` creates a new function.  Probably, the best approach are the functions `call` and `apply`.

Answer (score 2):

`pastJobs(this)` you are passing `this` as an argument 
and you're function doesn't accept arguments `function pastJobs()`. so doing `$(this)` in `pastJobs` is really out of context.

you could call the function `.call(this)`/`.apply(this)`, or `bind()` and then call it. (bind only binds this object but unlike apply or call doens't invoke the function.

keep in mind that `call` and `apply` takes arguments after `this` object in a different manner. The `call()` method takes arguments separately.
The `apply()` method takes arguments as an array.

you need something like

```
$(".search-result").each(function() {
    var x  = $(this).find('.past-positions ol').children()
    console.log(x)
    //this prints as expected
    pastJobs.call(this);
    // this does not
})
```