# Toggle particular element of multiple li with same class

Tags: jquery, html, mouseevent, mouseover

I have a code below

```
  <html>
  <body>
 <ul class="featured-categories__list row" id="featured-categories">

        <li class="featured-categories__list__item col-sm-4">               

            <a class="product-box__box-link product-box__box-link--light product-box__box-link--content-bottom" id="secCatLnk1" href="">
                <div class="featured-categories__list__item__text" style="display: block;">
                <h2 class="featured-categories__list__item__text__heading" id="secCatTxt1">DECORATIONS</h2>
                <div class="featured-categories__list__item__focus-text__call-to-action" id="secSubCatTxt1">Shop now</div>
                </div>
            </a>
            <div class="featured-categories__list__item__focus-text" style="display: none;">
                <h4 class="heading-level-five featured-categories__list__item__focus-text__heading" id="secDescText1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</h4>
                <p class="featured-categories__list__item__focus-text__call-to-action" id="secShopText1">Shop now</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="featured-categories__list__item col-sm-4">


            <a class="product-box__box-link product-box__box-link--light product-box__box-link--content-bottom" id="secCatLnk2" href="">
                <div class="featured-categories__list__item__text" style="display: block;">
                    <h2 class="featured-categories__list__item__text__heading" id="secCatTxt2">CHRISTMAS CARDS</h2>
                    <div class="featured-categories__list__item__focus-text__call-to-action" id="secSubCatTxt2">Shop now</div>
                </div>
            </a>
            <div class="featured-categories__list__item__focus-text" style="display: none;">
                <h4 class="heading-level-five featured-categories__list__item__focus-text__heading" id="secDescText2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</h4>
                <p class="featured-categories__list__item__focus-text__call-to-action" id="secShopText2">Shop now</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="featured-categories__list__item col-sm-4">           


            <a class="product-box__box-link product-box__box-link--light product-box__box-link--content-bottom" id="secCatLnk3" href="">
              <div class="featured-categories__list__item__text" style="display: block;">
                <h2 class="featured-categories__list__item__text__heading" id="secCatTxt3">GIFTS FOR HIM</h2>
                <div class="featured-categories__list__item__focus-text__call-to-action" id="secSubCatTxt3">Shop now</div>
              </div>
            </a>
            <div class="featured-categories__list__item__focus-text" style="display: none;">
                <h4 class="heading-level-five featured-categories__list__item__focus-text__heading" id="secDescText3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</h4>
                <p class="featured-categories__list__item__focus-text__call-to-action" id="secShopText3">Shop now</p>
            </div>  
        </li>              

    </ul>
   <script>  
        $(document).ready(function($){  
      $('.featured-categories__list__item').mouseover(function() {

            $('.featured-categories__list__item__text').hide();
            $('.featured-categories__list__item__focus-text').show();
        }).mouseout(function() {
            $('.featured-categories__list__item__text').show();
            $('.featured-categories__list__item__focus-text').hide();
        });
   });
   </script>
```

I am trying to show class "**featured-categories__list__item__focus-text**" when mouse hover on "**featured-categories__list__item**".

Above code works correctly but that is not working for the specific hovered element.

Instead it is showing all other elements which have same class.

I need to show the particular hovered element of the multiple li.

How to avoid this one. Please anyone look into this and share your ideas. Thanks

Comment: How do you expect it to be? `li` containing `featured-categories__list__item` classname on hover show `featured-categories__list__item__focus-text` ? and on hover out remove it?

Comment: @Mukyuu, yes on hover li, need to hide "featured-categories__list__item__text" and show "featured-categories__list__item__focus-text" and vice-versa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`$(this)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611233/jquery-this-selector-function-and-limitations) and [`.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) to specify which one of the `element` you target.

Example: `$(this).children('.featured-categories__list__item__text').hide();`

See snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.featured-categories__list__item').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).children('.featured-categories__list__item__text').hide();
    //$('.featured-categories__list__item__text').hide();
    // $('.featured-categories__list__item__focus-text').show();
    $(this).children('.featured-categories__list__item__focus-text').show();
  }).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).children('.featured-categories__list__item__text').show();
    //$('.featured-categories__list__item__text').show();
    // $('.featured-categories__list__item__focus-text').hide();
    $(this).children('.featured-categories__list__item__focus-text').hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="featured-categories__list row" id="featured-categories">

        <li class="featured-categories__list__item col-sm-4">               

            <a class="product-box__box-link product-box__box-link--light product-box__box-link--content-bottom" id="secCatLnk1" href="">
                <div class="featured-categories__list__item__text" style="display: block;">
                <h2 class="featured-categories__list__item__text__heading" id="secCatTxt1">DECORATIONS</h2>
                <div class="featured-categories__list__item__focus-text__call-to-action" id="secSubCatTxt1">Shop now</div>
                </div>
            </a>
            <div class="featured-categories__list__item__focus-text" style="display: none;">
                <h4 class="heading-level-five featured-categories__list__item__focus-text__heading" id="secDescText1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</h4>
                <p class="featured-categories__list__item__focus-text__call-to-action" id="secShopText1">Shop now</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="featured-categories__list__item col-sm-4">


            <a class="product-box__box-link product-box__box-link--light product-box__box-link--content-bottom" id="secCatLnk2" href="">
                <div class="featured-categories__list__item__text" style="display: block;">
                    <h2 class="featured-categories__list__item__text__heading" id="secCatTxt2">CHRISTMAS CARDS</h2>
                    <div class="featured-categories__list__item__focus-text__call-to-action" id="secSubCatTxt2">Shop now</div>
                </div>
            </a>
            <div class="featured-categories__list__item__focus-text" style="display: none;">
                <h4 class="heading-level-five featured-categories__list__item__focus-text__heading" id="secDescText2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</h4>
                <p class="featured-categories__list__item__focus-text__call-to-action" id="secShopText2">Shop now</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="featured-categories__list__item col-sm-4">           


            <a class="product-box__box-link product-box__box-link--light product-box__box-link--content-bottom" id="secCatLnk3" href="">
              <div class="featured-categories__list__item__text" style="display: block;">
                <h2 class="featured-categories__list__item__text__heading" id="secCatTxt3">GIFTS FOR HIM</h2>
                <div class="featured-categories__list__item__focus-text__call-to-action" id="secSubCatTxt3">Shop now</div>
              </div>
            </a>
            <div class="featured-categories__list__item__focus-text" style="display: none;">
                <h4 class="heading-level-five featured-categories__list__item__focus-text__heading" id="secDescText3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</h4>
                <p class="featured-categories__list__item__focus-text__call-to-action" id="secShopText3">Shop now</p>
            </div>  
        </li>              

    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <script>  
        $(document).ready(function($){  
      $('.featured-categories__list__item').mouseover(function() {
            $(this).find('a div .featured-categories__list__item__text').hide();

            $(this).find('.featured-categories__list__item__focus-text').show();
        }).mouseout(function() {
            $(this).find('a div .featured-categories__list__item__text').show();
            $(this).find('.featured-categories__list__item__focus-text').hide();

        });
   });
   </script>
```